# Using spark jars using databricks-connect>=13.0

Tags: pyspark, databricks, databricks-connect

With the newest version of `databricks-connect`, I cannot configure the extra jars I want to use. In the older version, I did that via

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('DataFrame').\
        config('spark.jars.packages','org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.3.0').getOrCreate()
```

How can I configure this with `databricks-connect>=13.0`?

Comment: Are you using azure databricks?

Comment: no our databricks is hosted on AWS